# Dataflow exception - "RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Premature EOF"

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Kicked off our pipeline (id: **2015-05-24_21_45_40-9907197960194601343**), and it failed with the below error. Looks like a problem with reading SideInputs.

Did something change in the service?

```
May 25, 2015, 2:53:09 PM
(ac187ee1445808a5): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Premature EOF at
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SideInputUtils$ReaderIterator.hasNext(SideInputUtils.java:127) at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.hasNext(TransformedIterator.java:43)
```

**Update**: Another job with the same problem: **2015-05-25_00_50_13-9599484476849123094**
**Update**: Another job with the same problem: **2015-06-04_18_22_47-8603825216881045184**

Comment: Investigating -- thanks for the Job IDs.

Comment: The error is most likely happening while reading the input used to produce that Side Input. Was this previously working (eg., this pipeline and that input) and recently broke or is this in new code?

Comment: Same code, same pipeline.

Comment: We're continuing to look into this. Does it reproduce reliably for you or does it happen intermittently? Is there anything special about the input or the amount of data that may have changed?

Comment: Are you using BigQuery for the input? If so, do you have any idea how big your rows are? Are you using any repeated fields or anything? The most likely case here is that something is failing while trying to read the actual input to use as the SideInput.

Comment: Correct, we're using BigQuery tables for our side inputs. The largest table has about 250k rows. Happens intermittently. Dataset does not have repeated fields.

Comment: @BenChambers: happened again on one of our jobs this morning. 2015-06-04_18_22_47-8603825216881045184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've not seen this error since. Seems to have been fixed on the Dataflow service side.